# Filter results in an array using a variable in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, if-statement

I have a collection of car Make and Models and I was wondering if there was a way of returning only the models that belong to certain makes using a variable as a condition? Thank you.

I have tried using if statements but maybe there is another way to accomplish this?

```
struct Section {

 var make: String
 var model: String!

}

var Cars = [
 Section(make: "BMW", model: ["A", "B", "C"]),
 Section(make: "Ford", model: ["D", "E", "F"]),
 Section(make: "Audi", model: ["G", "H", "I"])
]

var carMake = "BMW"

// aiming to print the models where make = carMake
// for example if carMake = "BMW" the print results would show "A", "B", "C"
```

Comment: `let model = Cars.first { $0.make == carMake }?.model`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
struct Section {

  var make: String
  var models: [String]

}
var cars = [
  Section(make: "BMW", models: ["A", "B", "C"]),
  Section(make: "Ford", models: ["D", "E", "F"]),
  Section(make: "Audi", models: ["G", "H", "I"])
]

var carMake = "BMW"

let carMaker = cars.first { (item) -> Bool in
  return item.make == carMake
}

if let carMaker = carMaker {
  print(carMaker.models)
} else {
  print("maker not found")
}
```

Comment: Use a variable instead of a hard coded string as in the question.

Comment: This would unnecessarily loop the the whole collection even if the object is at the first index position

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I did not catch the variable. Editing.

Comment: Change `.filter{...}.first` to `.first{...}` to prevent unnecessarily looping all elements. This will stop at first found element.

Comment: @staticVoidMan Yes, I forgot that. Thanks. BTW, there was no need for a minus vote. I see many "not the best" answers with thousands of pluses.

Comment: No man. I didn't downvote. Btw, u did `.first{...}.first`. +1 from me btw.

Comment: @staticVoidMan then thank you :)  and I hope I have a chance to talk with that down-voter.

Comment: Who ever downvoted, I guess it wud be because ur answer is too verbose. Keep it short and to the point. No point pasting the whole code. Just the `.first` part and maybe the `if let` is enugh. And... Definitely a little explanation. Just code looks like a baaad answer.

Comment: @staticVoidMan I have done some changes in his code; that's why I share the whole code. Whatever... I've done my job; with your help :) Have a nice day.